# why this regexp not working for first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match any number starting with 7-9 and must be digit only, it can be of any length
it is working but when i type only one character i.e 7 or 9
it still return false

here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>The test() method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.</p>
<p>Click the button to search a string for the character "e".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "94";
    var patt = new RegExp(/^[7-9]\d*/);
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most probably because you need to use just a regex literal - `var patt = /^[7-9]\d*/;`. Your code works (*true* is displayed) in my Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks @WiktorStribiżew